# Why does Control.Padding not affect the layout of a docked control?

Tags: c#, winforms

When a control with `Dock = DockStyle.Fill` is a child of another control with any padding set, the docked control completely ignores the padding of the container control. This does not happen if the container control is a subclass of type UserControl.

For example, consider the following two classes.

```
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner, System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))]
public class Container : Control
{
    public Container()
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Padding = new Padding(30, 30, 30, 30);
        BackColor = Color.Blue;
        Controls.Add(new Contained());
    }
}

public class Contained : Control
{
    public Contained()
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

The `DesignerAttribute` is simply for use as an aid in the designer. Unless you change the `Container` control to inherit from `UserControl`, a `Contained` control will not conform to the `Container` control's `Padding` property.

Why is this? Do I have to use UserControl in order to dock another control in a custom control with a custom padding?

Note: I am running VS11 with .NET 4.5. This could be the problem, but I can't test it on another version or platform to find out for sure.

Thanks,
Brandon

Comment: Is your real question "why?", or a better workaround?  See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/86ac4b22-a43a-4ef6-86ed-482596abf230

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A container control should derive from the ContainerControl class.  That gives it a number of "act like a container" behaviors.  Including observing the Padding property.